# Using multiprocessing Pool with PyQt5 signals

Tags: python, pyqt5

Using multiprocessing Pool with PyQt signal gives pickle error, any way I can send my progress in the loop back to the GUI?

```
class Analysis(QObject):

    progress = pyqtSignal(str)
    
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.result = []
        
    def worker_process(self, devices):
        for n1, n2 in itertools.product(self.data[devices[0]], self.data[devices[1]])
            if n1 == n2:
                self.result.append((n1, n2))
            self.progress.emit(f'Running on {device[0]} of network {n1} compare with {device[1]} of network {n2}')
            
    def run(self):
        devices = ['device_a', 'device_b', 'device_c', ...]
        pool = Pool(os.cpu_count() - 1)
        return_value = pool.map(self.worker_process, itertools.combinations(devices, 2)) <-- can't pickle Analysis object
```

Comment: Use a multiprocessing.Queue object to communicate back with the parent process.

Comment: I thought about it before. But can't seem to make it work. Signal can triggers slots from parent process to update the GUI widgets, but queue can't.

Comment: You would probably need to poll the queue.